# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 1} \cfrac{x^3 - 1}{x^2 - 2x + 1}$ without l'Hospital

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

I'm pretty stuck beyond identifying $$\lim_{x \to 1} \cfrac{x^3 - 1}{x^2 - 2x + 1} = \lim_{x \to 1} \cfrac{x^3 -1}{(x-1)^2}$$

Any hints? (Preferably not full answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
(x^3-1)=(x-1)(x^2+x+1).
$$
$$
x^2-2x+1=(x-1)^2.
$$
Then,
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\frac{x^2+x+1}{x-1}=?
$$

Answer (score 0):

It is $(x+2)+\frac{3}{x-1}$ see that the second term diverges to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

\begin{align} 
\lim_{x \to 1} \cfrac{x^3 - 1}{x^2 - 2x + 1}
&=
\lim_{x \to 1} \left(x+2+\cfrac{3}{x-1}\right)
=\dots
\end{align}